# V1 REST API queries for lsiting the Team & Member Name

Tags: api, rest

I am using the REST Call for getting the name of all the Teams from the Version-1.

The following URL gives me the List of all the Teams which are under Version-1

```
<Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Team?sel=Name
```

The following URL returns the Name of the Team which having id="12321"

```
<Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Team/12321?sel=Name
```

This returns the name of all the members

```
<Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Member?sel=Name
```

**My Questions are:**

1. How can I access the List of Team Name having id="12321","12231" & "13321" together ?
2. How can I access the List of Member Name which comes under the Team Name having id="12321" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access the List of Team Name having id="12321","12231" & "13321" together ?

Use commas to separate IDs in a query variable:

```
<Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Team?id=12321,12231,13321&sel=Name
```

> How can I access the List of Member Name which comes under the Team Name having id="12321" ?

Add "/member" to "/team"

```
<Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Team/12321/member?sel=Name
```

Usually APIs have plural "s" on these sorts of URLs (but thats not a requirement in any way):

```
<Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Teams?id=12321,12231,13321&sel=Name

<Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Teams/12321/members?sel=Name
```

Comment: Both the cases I tried. for accessing the members i tried <Server Base URL>/Rest-1.v1/Data/Team/12321/Member?sel=Name It gives me the following Errors: <Exception class="VersionOne.MetaException"><Message>Unknown AttributeDefinition: Team.Member</Message></Exception>

Comment: Well, you didn't state anything about what technology you are using, so I was assuming you needed help to model the URL. If you need help with the framework you are using then you should state that in your question and provide enough details to enable people to help you debug that sort of thing. As it is now there is no chance for anyone to help you.

Comment: I went through your answer and also refer the link http://community.versionone.com/?title=Developers%2FDeveloper-Library%2FDocumentation%2FAPI%2FEndpoints%2Frest-1.v1%252F%252FData I want to access only the XML information from the REST calls as mentioned that the individual URL works fine but when I tried to integrate It will give Error. Should I post the XML information ?